# Angular 6: How to track changes in a variable within a component?

Tags: angular

1. There is an array inside a page component;
2. In several different places within the component, a new element is added to this array (in the createMessage() method and inside the subscriber of the getIncomingMessagesStream() );
3. Each time a new element is added to the array, I need to perform several actions at once (scroll down the page and some actions yet);
4. Instead of performing additional actions in several places, I want to do this at one point inside the component, when a new value is added to my array.

How to do it?

In Angular 1.x was the $watch() method, but it isn't in Angular 2+.

```
I push a new message to messages array in several places:
- this.messageService.getIncomingMessagesStream().subscribe(...there...)
- createMessage() {...there...}

After I push a new message I need to do the same several actions:
- scroll window to bottom 
- etc...

Now I have to copy-paste the same actions in every place where I push a new message in messages array.

But I don't want to copy-paste this actions,
I want to perform them after I push a new element to messages array,
perform then automatically, from one point in code, without copy-paste,
I don't want to duplicate this actions.
```

Comment: why not add a onChange listener to the array, in the main component of subscription: Here https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges, thats if the object is data bound.

Comment: As I know ngOnChanges() detects only properties that get values an outside component via @Input() decorator. But I need to detect inner properties of an component; values for this properties doesn't come from outside.

Comment: How do you add new values to the array?

Comment: myArray.push(newEl); but I push a new element in two places in my component.

Comment: Could you write a method like `private pushValue(value) { this.myArray.push(value); doSomethingElse(); }`, and always use that method to add a value?

Comment: Also: do you use the array values in an `*ngFor` loop in the template? If so, can you show that markup in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. It is ES6 **Proxy** object.

**Proxy** is a special object whose meaning is to intercept calls to another object and, if it is necessary, modify them and perform additional actions.

```
let my_arr = [];
// Proxy(target, handler)
let arr_proxy = new Proxy(my_arr, {
    get(target, prop) {
        console.log(`\n Getting ${prop}`);
    console.log(`Perform needed actions after getting ${prop}`);
        return target[prop];
    },

    set(target, prop, value) {
        console.log(`\n Setting ${prop} ${value}`);
    console.log(`Perform needed actions after setting ${prop} ${value}`);
        target[prop] = value;
        return true;
    }
});

arr_proxy.push('new message text');
```

[image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Answer (score 1):

Also I found a solution with using of BehaviorSubject from RxJS.

```
// page.component.ts

private appData = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

constructor() {
    this.appData.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('New data', data);
    });
}

public addSomethingToAppData(something) {
    this.appData.next([...this.appData.getValue(), something]);
}
```

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject

What do you guys think is better to use, `ES6 Proxy` or `RxJS BehaviorSubject`, to make some actions after a new element was pushed to array?